# No apps connected when running expo start --dev-client

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I made iOS & Android builds with `"developmentClient": true` using the command `eas build --profile staging` in order to develop dynamically on physical device (iOS/Android) using `expo-dev-client`, below is my `eas.json` profile:

```
{
  "build": {
    "staging": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleStagingRelease"
      },
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest",
        "buildConfiguration": "Staging",
        "scheme": "Stage"
      },
      "developmentClient": true,
      "channel": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I install the app on my devices and on my laptop I run `expo start --dev-client`, and when I scan the QR, it opens the app directly without showing the expo dev launcher screen and when I hit r to reload it says `warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.`

Package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-dev-launcher": "1.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
  }
}
```

And yes, my both laptop and device are on same WiFi network.

So can someone guide me?

Comment: Are you logged into your expo account on both the expo-cli and expo app?

Comment: @Adii_Mathur yes